# ASP.NET Textbox does not contain a definition for 'value'

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

Software: Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition

I am reading "Programming ASP.NET 3.5", to execute the following upon clicking Button1, but there is red squiggly line under "Value"

![enter image description here][1]

But when I hover over Value I get the error

`'system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox' does not contain a definition for 'value'`

I am following things by the book, why do I get this error?

Comment: @JohnSaunders `Programming ASP.NET 3.5` by O'Reilly

Comment: Your `tdInnerHtml` issue is a different question. Please ask separately. When you do, be sure to include the markup, so there will be no guesswork involved.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Will open separate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the TextBox `Text` field

For example:

```
string strHrml = "";
strHtml += txtName.Text + "<br />";
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried, but the code doesn't work as expected, will add data to Original Post

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that the book is talking about the HtmlInputText control, not the TextBox control. TextBox has a Text property. HtmlInputText has a Value property.

Comment: I will look for HtmlInputText in Visual Web Developer

Answer (score 2):

TextBoxes have the `Text` property. Give it a try.